# Stack Overflow REST API

Tags: discussion

I am trying to access Stack Overflow directly from the command line in Linux. I just want to avoid going to the browser and type a question or keywords ... just too many steps.

Does Stack Overflow have any REST API, so I can develop my own access point?

Comment: Try to see: https://api.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See also https://stackapps.com, where you can ask questions about the use of the API.

Comment: Practically speaking I'd probably prefer a custom shortcut in an app launcher like https://ulauncher.io…

Comment: Uber meta duplicates: [Does Stack Overflow provide a public API for querying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16827/288751) and [Does Stack Overflow provide a public API to develop its app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202731/288751) and [How to make apps for StackOverflow? Is there an API for developing SO apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172619/288751),  etc.

Comment: *"I just want to avoid going to the browser and type a question or keywords ... just too many steps"* i can get wanting to avoid the browser but i assume you are implying other steps there than just posting a question since that is like one of the main things SO is

Answer (score 9):

In a word, yes, it does. See https://api.stackexchange.com/ for the documentation and the restrictions/throttles places on API usage.